# Autocalculate field in a django model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to calculate the *rounds* field in below's model everytime a new Tournament is created but to do it, I first need the number of players involved:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    rounds = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rounds = self.players.count() + 3
        super(Tournament, self).save()
```

The problems seems to be that if the *super* is not saved you can't access its m2m field:

> 'Tournament' instance needs to have a
>   primary key value before a
>   many-to-many relationship can be used.

Any suggestions?

_

I already tested

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tournament, self).save()
        self.rounds = self.players.count() + 3
        super(Tournament, self).save()
```

but *players.count()* always returns 0.

*post_save* signal was another of my attempts but I got a beautiful infinite recursion

```
def trigger_create_round(sender, **kwargs):
    tournament = kwargs['instance']
    tournament.rounds = tournament.players.count() + 3
    tournament.save()

post_save.connect(trigger_create_round, sender=Tournament, weak=False)
```

Thanks ;)

---

Edit:

Even using m2m_changed signal the problem persists:

```
def trigger_create_round(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        for val in pk_set:
            print val

m2m_changed.connect(trigger_create_round, sender=Tournament.players.through, weak=False)
```

but no values are printed though new players were added.

Note: I'm doing all Tournament management through Admin Website.

Comment: `if tournament.rounds != tournament.players.count() + 3: tournament.save()` Just a thought to break the loop. probably is a better way.

Comment: Many to many relationships are saved after the model itself is saved. That's why you have no access to the count from the model's `save` method. It's done this way because you can't save a many to many relationship without having a primary key for the model, and if it happens to be a new object, it wouldn't have a primary key yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here is not to trigger on save of the model, but of the m2m. Luckily, there's  a signal for that: [`m2m_changed`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed). The `instance` parameter to that signal is the model instance (here, the instance of Tournament) that is being changed.

Comment: Even using m2m_changed signal the problem persists. Please, see the _Edit_ on the original post.